# Brightness is not adjusting in the image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to achieve this result

[image]

but what I am trying is

```
Mat out = imread ("F:\\image.jpg");
Mat img2 = Mat(out.size(),out.type());
cv_Gamma(out,image ,0.7);
blending_overlay(image , out , image);
```

and this give me the following result

[image]

and the original image is

[image]

It looks that there is a lack of brightness in my image but when I increase the brightness it still not give the required result

Edit
Blending Overlay

```
void blending_overlay(Mat& img1 , Mat& img2 , Mat& out)
{

Mat result(img1.size(), CV_32FC3);
for(int i = 0; i < img1.size().height; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < img1.size().width; ++j){

        for (int c=0 ; c<img1.channels();c++){
            float target = (float)img1.at<uchar>(i, 3*j+c)/255.0 ;
            float blend =  (float)img2.at<uchar>(i, 3*j+c)/255.0 ;
            if(target > 0.5){
                result.at<float>(i, 3*j+c) = ((1 - (1-2*(target-0.5)) * (1-blend)));

                }
            else{
                result.at<float>(i, 3*j+c) = ((2*target) * blend);
                }
        }
    }
}
result.convertTo(out,CV_8UC3,255);
}
```

In fact I have tried every blending mode, what I understand about this is that I may multiply with a linear gradient which come from yellow to white, but how to make that gradient is not understandable for me. Any `algorithm` regarding this scenario would also be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see `blending_overlay` in the OpenCV documentation. Is that a function you defined? If so, we'll need to see that source too.

Comment: Now that you've changed the BGR values from your original question, it doesn't look like there's a lack of brightness. Can you give us some context? Where did `blending_overlay` come from and why do you think it should be able to reproduce the first image? Do you want a different algorithm? Do you just want help coming up with better BGR values for your overlay? Are you using trial and error to determine your BGR values?

Comment: blending overlay is functionality of Photoshop and it uses for blending 2 images , well because of lightening i think it may merge and discover the same result , Well i just want to get the above result , doesn't matter much which way to follow

Comment: Well i get the close result when i overlay the 2 same input images by using gamma with them , cv_Gamma is the function in @Andry answers

Comment: If you're using Photoshop to generate the "desired" image, you should tell us what steps you're using in Photoshop. Many functions will translate directly to other platforms.

Comment: No my desired result is not from photoshop , its from photo editing app , and I just want that type of result , its just for comparing , i want to learn how to edit only certain part of the image like in above 1st image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need gamma correction.

Take a look here:

http://subokita.com/2013/06/18/simple-and-fast-gamma-correction-on-opencv/

and the source of link above (with source/result pictures):

http://imagingsolution.net/program/opencv/gamma-correction/

Comment: Well am not getting the required result with it , btw why we use LUT ?

Comment: We use LUT for fast value transformation ecaluation. We have precomputed values in LUT, and then take it from lookup table instead of time consuming evaluation of gamma correction formula.

Comment: i tried it in every way its not solving the problem

Comment: To solve the problem you need more complex function then exponential. You can use spline (CatmulRom http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30838/Overhauser-Catmull-Rom-Splines-for-Camera-Animatio ) for instance. Then you'll have much more control on color mapping.

Comment: You'll get somethin like this: http://laurashoe.com/2010/04/01/wild-tone-curve-moves-in-lightroom-3-beta-2/

Comment: did it automatically adjust `Highlights` , `Light` , `Darks` and `shadows` ? or do it need to made them on my own

Comment: Computer does not know what do you want. If you can formulate your desired result in the form of some kind of target function (representing quality of result in scalar form) , then you can get parameters that minimizes/maximizes your target function.

Comment: Can we draw that curve in opencv without using c++ interface of .net ? like in the link ?

Comment: Yes, you can draw it in separate window using OpenCV functions, you can draw it using WinAPI GDI+ functions, you can use Qt GUI design tools etc.

Comment: your answer my solve not my problem but it take me very close to my solution